# Why do ferromagnetic materials have high magnetic permeability?

Tags: electromagnetism, ferromagnetism

What is peculiar about the structure of ferromagnetic materials which gives them their high magnetic permeability?

Comment: Maybe because dipoles in ferromagnetic materials can be easily aligned in the direction of magnetic field and the dipoles remain in their place even after the external magnetic field is removed.

Answer (score 0):

The ferromagnetic materials are mostly metals- like Iron itself, from where the name is derived. These materials have unpaired electrons and free ions, and thus, they have a net magnetic moment which is intrinsic to themselves.  These materials can support a large amount of magnetic flux intrinsically for a given magnetizing force. This essentially means that the material’s internal dipoles are easily oriented to an applied external magnetic field.

So, the presence of unpaired electrons gives rise to high magnetic permeability in these materials.